# Salesforse LWC not working navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc, aura-framework

`

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(function(devices) {
  devices.forEach(function(device) {
    console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
                " id = " + device.deviceId);
  });
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
});
```

**Unable to receive audio devices and microphone in LWC. Maybe someone faced this problem?**`

Answer (score 0):

With *Lightning Locker Service* a lot of the browsers native javascript objects (like `window`, `document`, etc.) are completely rewritten. This includes the `navigator.mediaDevices` object. Luckily Salesforce is making the switch to *Lightning Web Security* which opens some of these objects back up. It looks like you **do** have access to the navigator.mediaDevices object when Lightning Web Security is enabled. You can take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@sumit31swami/unlocking-the-locker-service-lightning-web-security-6b15a3ccd778) to see how to enable Lightning Web Security and use that object.